# Position sticky and scale

Tags: css

Got a problem with using `position: sticky` and `transform: scale()` at the same time.

If you hover over the icons on a left hand side, you will notice that the content jumps down and up by a pixel:

```css
.scroll-spy {
  position: sticky;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  top: 10px;
}

.scroll-spy a {
  color: var(--dark);
}

.scroll-spy a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scroll-spy a span {
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-spy a span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}

.scroll-spy a:hover span:after {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.scroll-spy>div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.scroll-spy i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #e21414;
  transition: color .2s ease-in;
}

.scroll-spy .active i {
  color: #48c417;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <aside class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">
    <div class="scroll-spy text-center">
      <div class="scroll-spy-job-type">
        <a href="#job-type" class="active">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
          <br />
          <span>Job type</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-spy-job-customer">
        <a href="#job-customer">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
          <br />
          <span>Customer</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-spy-job-details">
        <a href="#job-details">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
          <br />
          <span>Information</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
    <div class="add-edit-job-type" id="job-type">
      <h1>Job type</h1>

      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-edit-job-customer" id="job-customer">
      <h1>Customer details</h1>

      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-edit-job-information" id="job-details">
      <h1>Job information</h1>

      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `backface-visibility:hidden`, `transform-style: preserve-3d;`, `perspective: 1000px` with no change.

**Works with `position: fixed`.**

Happens in Chrome on Windows 10, not tested other browsers yet.

EDIT: here is the short video of the problem:

[image]

Anyone could shed some light on this?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue, neither in Chrome or Firefox :s

Comment: hm, maybe it is to do with chrome version. Mine is 63.0.3239.132

Comment: Same version as mine (not surprising for an evergreen browser). Just checked at windows 10, same Chrome version, not seeing the issue either. Does the snippet shows the issue for you? maybe it's something else in your full code version

Comment: Yes, snippet shows the issue as well, wouldn't post the question otherwise :)

Comment: @Facundo Corradini attached a gif showing the problem

Comment: that's extremely weird, it doesn't behave like that for me. Hovering the icons wouldn't move the main content at all. So can't help there, but I'll be following this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is not shifting for me when I hover over the links, so it is hard for me to fix that. So I have changed your scale transition to using a width transition. Could you let me know if you still see the 1px shift of the content.

```css
.scroll-spy {
  position: sticky;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  top: 10px;
}

.scroll-spy a {
  color: var(--dark);
}

.scroll-spy a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scroll-spy a span {
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-spy a span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .25s linear;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.scroll-spy a:hover span:after {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 80%;
}

.scroll-spy>div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.scroll-spy i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #e21414;
  transition: color .2s ease-in;
}

.scroll-spy .active i {
  color: #48c417;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <aside class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">
    <div class="scroll-spy text-center">
      <div class="scroll-spy-job-type">
        <a href="#job-type" class="active">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
          <br />
          <span>Job type</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-spy-job-customer">
        <a href="#job-customer">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
          <br />
          <span>Customer</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-spy-job-details">
        <a href="#job-details">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>
          <br />
          <span>Information</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
    <div class="add-edit-job-type" id="job-type">
      <h1>Job type</h1>

      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-edit-job-customer" id="job-customer">
      <h1>Customer details</h1>

      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-edit-job-information" id="job-details">
      <h1>Job information</h1>

      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```